# Why scrolling on a web page in Selenium v4.12.1 using JavascriptExecutor in Java is not working despite many cloud vendors advise the same?

Tags: remotewebdriver, selenium4, javascriptexecutor

In my environment using Selenium v4.12.1 with JDK 21, I could not get the page scrolling working using the JavascriptExecutor. What I tried are these various approaches...

```
  /**
   * scroll vertically(down)  https://testsigma.com/blog/scrolling-in-selenium/
   * @param driver
   * @param ratio -- between 0.5-1.0
   */
  public void scrollJSVertical(RemoteWebDriver driver,double ratio) {
      JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
      js.executeScript(String.format("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight * %.1f)",ratio));

  }
  /**
   * Scroll by the pixel value on x, y coordinates 
   * @param driver
   * @param x
   * @param y
   */
  public void scrollByJS(RemoteWebDriver driver,int x, int y) {
      JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
      js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,900)", "");
  }
  

  /**
   * scroll based on the visibility of the web element on the page
   * @param driver
   * @param elm WebElement present on the DOM
   */
  public void scrollJS4ElementVisibility(RemoteWebDriver driver,WebElement elm) {
      JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
      js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", elm);
  }
```

Comment: I saw the similar questions asked on SO already, but went ahead to post this question, because the version of Selenium v4.12.1 and JDK v21 I am using may be the differentiators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon building a demo project to test these methods, all of them worked just fine even including on the mobile device emulators. Only issue I am facing is they are not working for the Selenium script running on a cloud platform happened to be BrowserStack. I raised a support ticket with them and pursuing it.

Thanks,